# FBLoginView crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm experiencing a weird crash using `FBLoginView.`

**Scenario for crash:** My view with a `FBLoginView` instance loads and I don't login, I go back to my previous view and load my view with the `FBLoginView` instance again, this causes the app to crash and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
**It's working fine if I login and repeat the same thing.**

**Crash log:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'
```

**I found this:** [Very weird NSInvalidArgumentException with addSubview FBLoginView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475714/very-weird-nsinvalidargumentexception-with-addsubview-fbloginview) - which kind of describes the same problem, but I don't use `FBLoginView` in multiple views.

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!self.loginView) {
        self.loginView = [FBLoginView new];
        self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
        self.loginView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.loginView];
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you use compieled version of SDK or SDK in source codes? If you use sources, you can debug also FacebookSDK.